# Export HTTP Request data to Excel

Tags: http, export, response, export-to-excel, abap

I want to export data to an Excel file via HTTP Request. I have a class implementing the request handler interface.

I set the response body to something like `header1 \t header2 \t \n content1 \t content2 \t \n`

The content-type is `application/msexcel; charset=iso-8859-2`, and the `Content-Disposition`is set to `attachment; filename=Excel.xls`

This approach works nice for a server-side Javascript application, but when doing the same in ABAP the created Excel File has no columns or rows at all, the whole excel-formatted response body string is inserted in one cell.

Does anyone know, what is the difference between JS and ABAP?

Thanks and best Regards!

Comment: I think we need to see a little more code, have you tried with `response->set_header_field( name = 'Content-Type'  value = 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8' ).` ?

Answer (score 1):

I use this sample:

```
* list1 is an internal table
 loop at list1 INTO wa .

CONCATENATE output WA-weekday WA-x  WA-DTEXT
       WA-SCHKZ WA-BEGTM WA-ENDTM 
          CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>CR_LF
          INTO output SEPARATED BY TAB .
 endloop.
* utf-16le , format for excel file
app_type1 = 'APPLICATION/MSEXCEL;charset=utf-16le'.
* convert string to xstring
CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_STRING_TO_XSTRING'
  EXPORTING
    text     = output
    mimetype = 'APPLICATION/MSEXCEL;charset=utf-16le'
  IMPORTING
    buffer   = l_xstring.

CONCATENATE cl_abap_char_utilities=>byte_order_mark_little
  l_xstring
  INTO l_xstring IN BYTE MODE.

CALL METHOD cl_bsp_utility=>download

  EXPORTING
    object_s            = l_xstring
    content_type        = app_type
    content_disposition = 'attachment;filename=webforms.xls'
    response            = response
    navigation          = navigation.
```

You can also see this thread in sdn:
http://scn.sap.com/people/thomas.jung/blog/2004/08/09/bsp-download-to-excel-in-unicode-format